# Spring boot with camel spring boot starter - Routes getting loaded twice

Tags: spring, spring-boot, apache-camel

I am trying to use spring boot with camel. While defining routes using camel routebuilder, it seems two routes are being created for one route definition. Below are the details of project set up -

- pom.xml

```
<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.10</version>
        <relativePath /> 
</parent>
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <!-- Camel BOM -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel.springboot</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-spring-boot-bom</artifactId>
            <version>3.20.4</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
<dependencies>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-activemq</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel.springboot</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel.springboot</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-jms-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

RouteBuilder

```
@Component
public class MyRouteBuilder extends RouteBuilder{
@Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {
     from(jms:queue:queue11222?transacted=true&receiveTimeout=10000&connectionFactory=myconfactory).autoStartup(true)
                        .log("Received message from ESB queue: ${body}")
                        .log("JMS transaction set");
   }
}
```

But if I remove "@Component" from the RouteBuilder class, only one route is created. As per documentation here - https://camel.apache.org/camel-spring-boot/3.20.x/index.html; it mentions to annotate the RouteBuilder with @Component.

Could anyone please advise what is the recommended way to configure camel with spring boot to avoid duplicate routes?

Comment: Try adding a .routeid("name") on the route. If it gets defined twice it will fail and the original path may be revealed in the stack.